# Определить какой язык программирования используется в программе по синтаксису

Tags: любой-язык

Язык используется для написания макросов в российской CAD/CAM системе Гемма.

1. REM - комментарии
2. DIM - массивы
3. COUNT#, NUMBER# - # тип int
4. LINE@, SURFACE@ - Объекты на чертеже
5. FILENAME$, STRING$ - строки
6. X, Y, VAR - тип FLOAT

Хочу изучить макропрограммирование, а описания языка недостаточно. Нужно узнать какой язык наиболее похож.

```
REM Изучаю синтаксис GML
REM Фрагмент программы, выводящей окно
call DLG_SHOW("тут какой-то текст",   0, 0, 670, 475, ret#)
```

В чем-то похож на VisualBasic.Надеюсь достаточно данных.

Comment: собственно basic и есть, либо один из диалектов.

Comment: [Макроязык представляет собой упрощенный вариант языка Basic.](https://sapr.ru/article/6753)